# Can you use fourier analysis to identify recurring transactions?

Tags: fourier-transform

My banking app provides some predictive analysis on what upcoming bills I have. This got me thinking on how the bank does this analysis. Is it possible to use fourier analysis with my transaction history as input, to identify recurring transactions and predict upcoming bills?

If so, could someone provide an example in R/Python. Thank you.

Comment: Could you tell us something about the data you intend to use?  I would also like to suggest that asking questions about a proposed procedure to solve a problem tends to be frustrating unless the procedure is a good one.  It's usually not helpful to learn how to apply a useless or misleading or inefficient procedure.  It's almost always better to state your problem clearly and ask how to solve it.